# css center a table inside a div and center that div inside another div

Tags: html, css

I writing a VSTS dashboard widget and I need some help with styling. I want to have a table generated (through code) display data for admins. I need help with the styling.

> I would like to center the div containing the table inside of the parent div. But I also want the table to have a scrollbar if the content exceeds the height of the widget itself, and stylistically I want the scrollbar to appear on the edge of the child div.

Here is the html code inside my index.html:

```
<body>
    <div class="widget">
        <h2 class="title">My Widget Title</h2>
        <div id="loader"></div>
        <div id="tableContainer" class="animate-bottom">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Note**: The loader div is used to display a loader while the app fetches data from an API. When data arrives, I do the following: `document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";`

Here is my style.css file:

```
.widget {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#tableContainer {
    text-align: initial;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

tbody {
    height: 575px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: block;
}

table {
    margin: auto;
}

h2 {
    text-align: initial;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Currently the child div gets centered horizontally but the scrollbar appears displaced inside the child div. How can I get the scrollbar to touch the right edge of the child div.

Comment: @Joel How is it useless? This is a css stylistic question. I provided both the html of the index.html file and my styles.css code, as well as a background of the application I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example shows a widget with a fixed height that scrolls if the containing table's height is greater.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ukwpfgj5/8/

HTML

```
<div class="widget">
    <h2 class="title">My Widget Title</h2>
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <div id="tableContainer" class="animate-bottom">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                ...
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.widget {
    text-align: center;
}
#tableContainer {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```